# GLSL Fails to compile

Tags: opengl, struct, glsl

Here is the shader from an example program I'm working with:

```
static const char* pFS = "                                                          \n\
#version 330                                                                        \n\
                                                                                    \n\
const int MAX_POINT_LIGHTS = 2;                                                     \n\
const int MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS = 2;                                                      \n\
                                                                                    \n\
in vec4 LightSpacePos;                                                              \n\
in vec2 TexCoord0;                                                                  \n\
in vec3 Normal0;                                                                    \n\
in vec3 WorldPos0;                                                                  \n\
in vec3 Tangent0;                                                                   \n\
                                                                                    \n\
out vec4 FragColor;                                                                 \n\
                                                                                    \n\
struct BaseLight                                                                    \n\
{                                                                                   \n\
    vec3 Color;                                                                     \n\
    float AmbientIntensity;                                                         \n\
    float DiffuseIntensity;                                                         \n\
};                                                                                  \n\
                                                                                    \n\
struct DirectionalLight                                                             \n\
{                                                                                   \n\
    struct BaseLight Base;                                                          \n\
    vec3 Direction;                                                                 \n\
};                                                                                  \n\
                                                                                    \n\
struct Attenuation                                                                  \n\
{                                                                                   \n\
    float Constant;                                                                 \n\
    float Linear;                                                                   \n\
    float Exp;                                                                      \n\
};                                                                                  \n\
                                                                                    \n\
struct PointLight                                                                           \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    struct BaseLight Base;                                                                  \n\
    vec3 Position;                                                                          \n\
    Attenuation Atten;                                                                      \n\
};                                                                                          \n\
                                                                                            \n\
struct SpotLight                                                                            \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    struct PointLight Base;                                                                 \n\
    vec3 Direction;                                                                         \n\
    float Cutoff;                                                                           \n\
};                                                                                          \n\
                                                                                            \n\
uniform int gNumPointLights;                                                                \n\
uniform int gNumSpotLights;                                                                 \n\
uniform DirectionalLight gDirectionalLight;                                                 \n\
uniform PointLight gPointLights[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];                                          \n\
uniform SpotLight gSpotLights[MAX_SPOT_LIGHTS];                                             \n\
uniform sampler2D gColorMap;                                                                \n\
uniform sampler2D gShadowMap;                                                               \n\
uniform sampler2D gNormalMap;                                                               \n\
uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;                                                                  \n\
uniform float gMatSpecularIntensity;                                                        \n\
uniform float gSpecularPower;                                                               \n\
                                                                                            \n\
float CalcShadowFactor(vec4 LightSpacePos)                                                  \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    vec3 ProjCoords = LightSpacePos.xyz / LightSpacePos.w;                                  \n\
    vec2 UVCoords;                                                                          \n\
    UVCoords.x = 0.5 * ProjCoords.x + 0.5;                                                  \n\
    UVCoords.y = 0.5 * ProjCoords.y + 0.5;                                                  \n\
    float Depth = texture(gShadowMap, UVCoords).x;                                          \n\
    if (Depth <= (ProjCoords.z + 0.005))                                                    \n\
        return 0.5;                                                                         \n\
    else                                                                                    \n\
        return 1.0;                                                                         \n\
}                                                                                           \n\
                                                                                            \n\
vec4 CalcLightInternal(struct BaseLight Light, vec3 LightDirection, vec3 Normal,            \n\
                       float ShadowFactor)                                                  \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    vec4 AmbientColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) * Light.AmbientIntensity;                   \n\
    float DiffuseFactor = dot(Normal, -LightDirection);                                     \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    vec4 DiffuseColor  = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);                                                  \n\
    vec4 SpecularColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);                                                  \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    if (DiffuseFactor > 0) {                                                                \n\
        DiffuseColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) * Light.DiffuseIntensity * DiffuseFactor;    \n\
                                                                                            \n\
        vec3 VertexToEye = normalize(gEyeWorldPos - WorldPos0);                             \n\
        vec3 LightReflect = normalize(reflect(LightDirection, Normal));                     \n\
        float SpecularFactor = dot(VertexToEye, LightReflect);                              \n\
        SpecularFactor = pow(SpecularFactor, gSpecularPower);                               \n\
        if (SpecularFactor > 0) {                                                           \n\
            SpecularColor = vec4(Light.Color, 1.0f) *                                       \n\
                            gMatSpecularIntensity * SpecularFactor;                         \n\
        }                                                                                   \n\
    }                                                                                       \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    return (AmbientColor + ShadowFactor * (DiffuseColor + SpecularColor));                  \n\
}                                                                                           \n\
                                                                                            \n\
vec4 CalcDirectionalLight(vec3 Normal)                                                      \n\
{                                                                                                \n\
    return CalcLightInternal(gDirectionalLight.Base, gDirectionalLight.Direction, Normal, 1.0);  \n\
}                                                                                                \n\
                                                                                            \n\
vec4 CalcPointLight(struct PointLight l, vec3 Normal, vec4 LightSpacePos)                   \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    vec3 LightDirection = WorldPos0 - l.Position;                                           \n\
    float Distance = length(LightDirection);                                                \n\
    LightDirection = normalize(LightDirection);                                             \n\
    float ShadowFactor = CalcShadowFactor(LightSpacePos);                                   \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    vec4 Color = CalcLightInternal(l.Base, LightDirection, Normal, ShadowFactor);           \n\
    float Attenuation =  l.Atten.Constant +                                                 \n\
                         l.Atten.Linear * Distance +                                        \n\
                         l.Atten.Exp * Distance * Distance;                                 \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    return Color / Attenuation;                                                             \n\
}                                                                                           \n\
                                                                                            \n\
vec4 CalcSpotLight(struct SpotLight l, vec3 Normal, vec4 LightSpacePos)                     \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    vec3 LightToPixel = normalize(WorldPos0 - l.Base.Position);                             \n\
    float SpotFactor = dot(LightToPixel, l.Direction);                                      \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    if (SpotFactor > l.Cutoff) {                                                            \n\
        vec4 Color = CalcPointLight(l.Base, Normal, LightSpacePos);                         \n\
        return Color * (1.0 - (1.0 - SpotFactor) * 1.0/(1.0 - l.Cutoff));                   \n\
    }                                                                                       \n\
    else {                                                                                  \n\
        return vec4(0,0,0,0);                                                               \n\
    }                                                                                       \n\
}                                                                                           \n\
                                                                                            \n\
vec3 CalcBumpedNormal()                                                                     \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    vec3 Normal = normalize(Normal0);                                                       \n\
    vec3 Tangent = normalize(Tangent0);                                                     \n\
    Tangent = normalize(Tangent - dot(Tangent, Normal) * Normal);                           \n\
    vec3 Bitangent = cross(Tangent, Normal);                                                \n\
    vec3 BumpMapNormal = texture(gNormalMap, TexCoord0).xyz;                                \n\
    BumpMapNormal = 2.0 * BumpMapNormal - vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);                              \n\
    vec3 NewNormal;                                                                         \n\
    mat3 TBN = mat3(Tangent, Bitangent, Normal);                                            \n\
    NewNormal = TBN * BumpMapNormal;                                                        \n\
    NewNormal = normalize(NewNormal);                                                       \n\
    return NewNormal;                                                                       \n\
}                                                                                           \n\
                                                                                            \n\
void main()                                                                                 \n\
{                                                                                           \n\
    vec3 Normal = CalcBumpedNormal();                                                       \n\
    vec4 TotalLight = CalcDirectionalLight(Normal);                                         \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    for (int i = 0 ; i < gNumPointLights ; i++) {                                           \n\
        TotalLight += CalcPointLight(gPointLights[i], Normal, LightSpacePos);               \n\
    }                                                                                       \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    for (int i = 0 ; i < gNumSpotLights ; i++) {                                            \n\
        TotalLight += CalcSpotLight(gSpotLights[i], Normal, LightSpacePos);                 \n\
    }                                                                                       \n\
                                                                                            \n\
    vec4 SampledColor = texture2D(gColorMap, TexCoord0.xy);                                 \n\
    FragColor = SampledColor * TotalLight;                                                  \n\
}";
```

GLSL complains that:
Error compiling FS: 'Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:24: error(#132) Syntax error: 'Base' parse error
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated'

However, the GLSL standard clearly states:

> ...it also
>   creates a variable of that type called variableName. As in C/C++, the
>   variable name can be omitted. Structs cannot contain variables of
>   sampler types. ***They can contain variables of other struct types.***
>   Structs define a named type. But there are limits on the type
>   qualifiers that can be used with struct types. Uniforms can use struct
>   types, as well as regular globals, locals, and constant variables.
>   Structs cannot be used with any other storage qualifiers.

Why doesn't this compile?

Comment: @NicolBolas: l24 = 'struct BaseLight Base;'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct BaseLight Base;
```

GLSL is not **C**. You don't use the `struct` keyword like that. `BaseLight` is a typename, so you just say `BaseLight Base`. You do it correctly when you create `PointLight`, so I don't know why you got it wrong so consistently with your uses of `BaseLight`.